# How to creating an app with Laravel + EmberJS

Tags: laravel, ember.js

I need to create an app using EmberJS 2.18 for the frontend and Laravel ^6.0 for the backend. I found a guide (here: https://culttt.com/2015/04/06/getting-started-with-laravel-and-ember/) but it's 5 years old and after following its advice it referred to directories that don't exist so I couldn't complete it and I don't know how to check if it's working.

I have zero experience with either framework and I'm trying to piece this all together. Is there an easy to follow tutorial for how to set this up?

Comment: Any reason that you are starting a new application with Ember 2.18? Ember 2.18 was released in January 2018 and is out of support for a long time already. Current version is 3.23.

Comment: These are the requirements that were given me. I don't have much choice in the matter.

Comment: I would question that decision. Ember 2.18 is way harder to learn than current Ember. If you have knowledge of JavaScript you will be productive with modern Ember Octane within days will it may take you weeks with pre-Octane Ember. Myself using [Laravel JSON API](https://laravel-json-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) very productive with [Ember Data](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/).